# Excel Data Manipulation using VB.NET using Interop libraries

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am newbie to VB.NET and was trying to make a windows form application to copy data from a master excel workbook to a new file using a template.With the code below i am able to create a new file with a template.

What i want to do now is copy data from a master excel file and paste it to the new file i have created based on the range selection using a check box in the windows form.The data is scattered in the master workbook in different sheets and i don't know where to start or how to start. any help or advise will be appreciated.
For Eg: From the form if i select sheet 1 & sheet 2 the code should copy data from sheet 1 first and below that it should copy data from sheet 2 & so on

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")
        Return
    End If

    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("C:\Source.CSV")


    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\New.CSV", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
     Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\New.CSV")
End Sub
```

Comment: Why my question was down voted? if no one leaves any comment below how can beginners like me can improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completely revamped the code.

So, `TestExcel` function accepts array of strings - sheets' names. You can generate it based on your checkboxes and pass it to this function. All the explanations go in comments.

```
Sub IAmCaller()
    TestExcel({"Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"}) '//Pass sheets' names
End Sub

Sub TestExcel(SheetsNames As String())
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application With {.Visible = False}
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!")
        Return
    End If

    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlTempBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlTempSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
    '// This variable will hold the last row where data will be inserted
    Dim lastRow As Long

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Master.xlsx")

    '// Either create new workbook based on default template or your own template:
    '// Default template
    xlTempBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    '// Your own template
    xlTempBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(xlApp.TemplatesPath + "NEWTEMPLATE.xltx")

    '// First sheet of temp workbook
    xlTempSheet = xlTempBook.Sheets(1)

    For Each sheetName In SheetsNames
        '// Select some range and copy to new sheet in new temp book
        xlRange = xlWorkBook.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1:C10")
        '// Calculate last row
        With xlTempSheet
            '// We calculate last row by column A.
            '// Feel free to change it to appropriate one.
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
            '// Next empty cell.
            '// Then End method (above) returns last cell.
            '// If sheet is clear, then the last cell is always in the first row.
            '// However, if there's some data, then last cell won't be the first.
            '// In this case we need to make a shift one cell down.
            If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow += 1
            '// Actual copying.
            '// In this case we copy into A column (i.e. top-left cell).
            '// As your master range contains formulas and you don't need them,
            '// you have two choices:
            '// 1) Use clipboard
            '// 2) Use Value property
            '// The first one is easy to implement.
            '// The second one requires accepting side to have same form,
            '// i.e. the accepting range must have same number of rows and columns.

            '// Case 1. Using clipboard.
            xlRange.Copy() : .Cells(lastRow, "A").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)

            '// Case 2. Using Value property
            .Cells(lastRow, "A").Resize(xlRange.Rows.Count, xlRange.Columns.Count).Value = xlRange.Value

        End With
    Next



    xlTempBook.SaveAs("C:\New.CSV", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
    xlTempBook.Close(False)
    xlWorkBook.Close(False)
    xlApp.Quit()

    xlRange = Nothing
    xlWorkSheet = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()


    WriteLine("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\New.CSV")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, The master sheet contains formulas and i dont them to be copied over to the final sheet so i tried using rng.PasteSpecial(xlTempBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1))  but its giving me error

Comment: also would you be able to show me some sample how can i add data from multiple sheets in source file to a single sheet in destination based on a check box selection.

Comment: @george86 Source file is the master sheet? Then what is *multiple sheets*? Could you make a picture clear?

Comment: Ok. I have the this master work that contains Many sheets , Say like Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3 e.t.c. I want to give a check box option in the form for the user to select  the sheets he wants to copy. If the user select sheet 1, 2 & 3 the code should run and copy data from all threes sheets to the destination file. Sheet 2 data should be copied below the sheet 1 data.

Comment: @george86 So, to be specific, all data from master workbook goes to *one* sheet - one after another. Correct? :)

Comment: yes based on selection of sheets. It would be even better if i can select Range in each sheets.in case i dont want the whole data in some sheets. Am i asking too much ..